# Vuelidate "required" ignoring value attributed in JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I created a wizard form which uses Vuelidate to validate it's fields. The big majority of the fields have only the "required" function, so my validations are something close to this:

```js
validations() {
    if (this.currentStep === 0) {
      return {
        person: {
          name: {
            required,
          },
          age: {
            required,
          },
        }
      }
    } else if (this.currentStep === 1) {
      return {
        person: {
          street: {
            required,
          },
          city: {
            required,
          },
          state: {
            required,
          },
        }
      }
```

The thing is, I am receiving this data from an API, so the user can either fill the fields himself, or let the machine do it for him. When I receive the data, I make this attribution in a function in JS close to the following:

```js
attributeData():
  this.person.name = apiData.name;
  this.person.age = apiData.age;
  this.person.street = apiData.street;
  this.person.city = apiData.city;
  this.person.state = apiData.state;
```

If the user types the info, then everything works fine. If I receive the info from the API, then I get the error as if the input was empty.

This is how every field in my HTML is organized:

```html
<b-form-group label="Name">
  <b-form-input
   v-model="person.name"
   type="text"
   size="sm"
   :class="{
     'is-invalid':
       submitted && $v.person.name.$error,
   }"
   ></b-form-input>
    <div
     v-if="submitted && $v.person.name.$error"
     class="invalid-feedback"
     >
     <span v-if="!$v.person.name.required"
     >Name is required.</span
    >
  </div>
</b-form-group>
```

Any idea of why Vuelidate can't recognize the values when I attribute them directly in JS? I've made this exact same way in another page and it worked. In DevTools even the $model of Vuelidate has the value that came from the API.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.  The basic explanation is that data is wrong. "In DevTools even the $model of Vuelidate has the value that came from the API" - is it for another page or this one?

Comment: So, yeah, when the user types the info himself, the $model receives it, but the validation still accuses it of being wrong. When it comes from the API, it stays null. I'm guessing I'm using $v.$touch and $v.$reset wrongly, but I'm not sure. About data being wrong, it's literally the person object with the attributes with null values. In DevTools, my person object appears empty until I give it any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may occur if you have two elements using the same identifier.
Example:

data: {user_id: null} and setted v-model="user_id" in one input.

And another element input with: id:user_id

Beware if you are not manipulating the value and then it lost the reference, example:

data: {user: {name: null}}

And you filled it by API but latter in created or mounted put something like:
this.user = {}

The reference user.name was gone and validation can't work anymore.